# react-redux/react-router: how to change state on Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

On *page A*, I have a react-router `<Link>` that leads to *page B*. On *page B*, I have a button that tries to do something on server, and either leads to *page C* (success) or stay on *page B* (failure). In this last case, a message appears on the page to show the error.

When I have the error message on *page B*, if I use the browser back button to go back on *page A* then click the `<Link>` again to go on *page B*, the message is still here.

So it seems the state isn't reset when using a `<Link>` , and I wonder what is the good way of changing state on a `<Link>`?

---

Edit:
To make it clearer, on *page A* you have a `<Link>` to *page B*. On *page B* you have a button to submit your login informations (login and password).

When you click, an **action** do the request to the server:

```
function authRequest() {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.AUTH_REQUEST
  };
}

function authReceive(authToken) {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.AUTH_RECEIVE,
    authToken
  };
}

function authError(errors) {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.AUTH_ERROR,
    errors
  };
}

export function fetchLogin(email, password) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(authRequest());
    const urlApi = `//${AUTH_BACKEND_HOST}:${AUTH_BACKEND_PORT}/${AUTH_BACKEND_URL.login}`
    fetch(urlApi, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password
      })
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.ok) {
        response.json().then(function(json) {
          dispatch(authReceive(json.key));
          dispatch(push('/'));
        });
      } else {
        response.json().then(function(json) {
          dispatch(authError(JSON.stringify(json)));
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(function(ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    });
  };
}
```

... and if it fails, a **reducer** add the error message in the state:

```
const initialState = {
  authToken: '',
  isFetching: false,
  errors: ''
}

export default function (state=initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionType.AUTH_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
        errors: ''
      };
    case actionType.AUTH_RECEIVE:
      return authLogin(state, action);
    case actionType.AUTH_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        errors: (JSON.parse(action.errors))
      };
  }
  return state;
}

function authLogin(state, action) {
  const { authToken } = action;
  return {
    ...state,
    isFetching: false,
    errors: '',
    authToken
  };
}
```

... and finally, the **presenter** has a render method with a `<p>` that shows the error if it's in the state:

```
render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>Email <input ref="email" /></label>
        <label>Password <input ref="password" type="password" /></label><br />
        <p className="error">{this.props.errors.non_field_errors}</p>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
```

So as I said, if it shows the error then I go back on *page A* then on *page B* again by clicking the link, the message is still there.

Thank you.

Comment: if the state wasn't reset, it means `componentWillMount` of `ComponentB` wasn't invoked. Include your route configuration, it will give better idea

Comment: You are right, there are no such functions as *componentSomething* in this app I'm working on. I saw them on some examples but none are used in this app and I still can manage to register a user then connect and navigate on the main page.

Answer (score 3):

Redux is all about consistently, cleanly tracking your application's state, independently of what components are using that state. So it's not surprising that the failure state stays, unless you're specifically clearing it.

So the next question is, in what circumstances do you want to clear the failure state? (In what circumstances do you want to forget the fact that page B's operation failed?)

1. When following a `<Link>` from A to B? You could do this with [`<Link>`'s `onClick`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onclicke), but it seems overly specific. (What if the user gets to B some other way? And why should A's Link have to care about about B's failure state?)
2. When B mounts? (In other words, "every time I enter B, treat it as a blank slate.") To implement this, use [`componentWillMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentwillmount).
3. When B unmounts? (In other words, "every time I leave B, throw away the status of any operations within B.") To implement this, use [`componentWillUnmount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#unmounting-componentwillunmount).

I'm guessing that option 2 or 3 would fit your design best. So then you'd dispatch an appropriate action from `componentWillMount` or `componentWillUnmount`, and the reducer for that action would clear any failure state.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that, I saw some functions like *componentSomething* exist but I didn't use this. So yes I want B to be blank everytime I go on it.

Comment: Regarding (3), I don't think we need to explicitly clear state upon unmount, react does that for us

Comment: @Deadfish - I should have been confirmed the terminology. If, by "state," he means the application state that's kept in the Redux store (which was my assumption), it lives as long as the Redux store does (probably the whole application). If he means the React component state for page B, then you're right, it's cleared when page B's component unmount (and is also initialized when the page B component mounts, so I don't think it could cause his problem).

Comment: @JoshKelley yes I'm talking about a store state, not a component state. I think... I edited my question.